# ExtJS: Fetching information from selected store in combo

Tags: extjs

I have the following ExtJS Textfield that lives in a  form. I have a store called 
`store_Product` that fetches data via ajax proxy and suggest them to the PCODE field.

In reality this store has many other fields such as `price`,`color`,`size` and so on..
I am trying to set an onchange listener on this field such that when the user select the PCODE, it delivers other information (of the Product selected) to other fields in the page.

The code bellows work. The `console.log(store_Product.data)` correctly fetches the data from the model. **However**, the data fetched is of the whole store. I just want the one selected. How would I change this code to do that.

```
            {
                fieldLabel: 'PCODE  ',
                name: 'pcode',
                typeAhead: true,
                xtype: 'combo',
                store: store_Product,
                displayField: 'pcode',
                valueField: 'pcode',
                allowBlank:false,
                minChars:1,
                forceSelection:true,
                hideTrigger:true,
                queryDelay: 0,
                listeners:{
                   change: function(combo,value){
                       console.log(store_Product.data)
                   }
                }
            }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's gonna log everything. Have you tried looking at the `value` you're receiving in the handler?

```
change: function(combo, value) {
   console.log(value);
   var idx= store_Product.find('pcode', value),
       record = store_Product.getAt(idx);

   console.log(record);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `pcode` is the [id](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty) of your records, you can use [`Store.getById`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getById):

```
store_Product.getById(value)
```